# How to stop loading the UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I  created number of UIWebviews and add it to my view. And gave load request. I want to stop loading the uiwebview with tag=10. How can this implement?

Answer (score 21):

try something like this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [self.view viewWithTag:10];
if(webView)
{
    [webView stopLoading];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write webView stopLoading method in `viewWillDisappear`

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([webView isLoading])
    {
        [webView stopLoading];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the `UIWebView` from loading in `UIWebViewDelegate` method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView  shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UINavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(webView.tag==10)
    {
        return  NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It will Help you.