# Stop UIWebView from loading the set URL everytime when it gets loaded

Tags: ios, webview, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an app with several UIWebView's and when I press the button to bring one up it loads the set URL.

Now I would like this to happen the first time, as the webpage needs to load, but what if I want to flick between the different Views? I would like it to stay at the page it was when I left it.

Now I do believe this can be done with the UITabBarController, but it takes up to much screen real estate for what I want to achieve, so I have implemented the switch with a UISegmentedController.

I have this code to load the website initially in my viewDidLoad method:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";  
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

and on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577557/892628) I found that you can have a webpage stop loading with:

```
UIWebView *webView = [self.view viewWithTag:10];
if(webView)
 {
  [webView stopLoading];
 }
```

Now I know I need to adjust that answer, but is what I am trying to do possible, or will the use of a SegmentedControl always cause the UIWebView to reload and will I be forced to use the TabBar?

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSUserDefaults to record if it is the first time or not and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right path - working with NSUserDefaults now:-)