# UIwebView - load the URL it was left with upon dismissView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsuserdefaults

I have the following code that allows me to load a set URL each time, placed in my viewDidLoad method:

```
NSString *urlAddress =  @"http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Now the user can of course go to any webpage from here and if the user decides to dismiss the view I want for them to be able to return to it.

Now I have this code, through reading various forums and searches:

again the viewDidLoad - now looks like this:

```
NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [_webView request];
NSURL *currentURL = [currentRequest URL];

if(currentURL != nil) 
{
NSString *urlAddress = currentRequest;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
else {
NSString *urlAddress =  @"http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

and in my viewDidUnLoad I have this:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload {

NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [_webView request];
NSURL *currentURL = [currentRequest URL];
NSLog(@"Current URL is %@", currentURL.absoluteString);


[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:currentRequest delegate:self];

}
```

a) Am I on the right track for achieving this?

b) I have a warning created on this line : `NSString *urlAddress = currentRequest;
which is:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSURLRequest *__strong'

Any help is appreciated:-)

Thank you:-)

[PS I started this problem out in this question, but felt it was worth a new one, so forgive me if you do not think the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711027/stop-uiwebview-from-loading-the-set-url-everytime-when-it-gets-loaded)

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *urlAddress = currentRequest;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Could just be

```
[_webView loadRequest:currentRequest];
```

You might want to experiment with not unloading the view/view controller when the user dismisses it then there won't be a time delay when the user brings it back. (Maybe you could instead make it hidden instead of unloading it for example when the user dismisses it, or send it to the back of the navigation controller stack, assuming you have one as the root view controller).

P.S.
Your warning is because you're trying to assign an NSURLRequest object to an NSString object.

Comment: Thank you for the round of advices:-) I figured out a few things, but you gave a different way of looking at things:-)